# How to select for percentage and count calculatio from different table

Tags: mysql

Please i need help to complete the code to do the following:

1. calculate the percentage of voters who have voted based on batches.
2. get the number of voters by batch.

my table :

```
voters table
    +-------------+-------------+----------------+
    | stud_id     | name        | batch          |
    +-------------+-------------+----------------+
    | 1           | Peter       | 2016           | 
    | 2           | John        | 2017           | 
    | 3           | Wick        | 2017           | 
    +-------------+-------------+----------------+

vote table
    +-------------+----------------+
    | vote_id     | stud_id        |
    +-------------+----------------+
    | 1           | 1              | 
    | 2           | 2              |
    +-------------+----------------+
```

ive tried this query:

```
SELECT voters.batch,COUNT(*) AS voted_batch, 100.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vote) AS percentage
FROM vote JOIN voters WHERE voters.stud_id=vote.stud_id
GROUP BY batch asc
```

the code can only display the percentage of voting (not from a batch) and can only do a total of voting and I am confused to show a total of voters

and my expected table selection is:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| batch       |total_batch     | voted_batch    | percentage     |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|2016         | 1              | 1              | 100            |
|2017         | 2              | 1              | 50             |    
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Much appreciate for your support, thank you very much.

Comment: well, posted. but only the code i posted that successfully shows the result :(

Comment: Use join ON condition, not WHERE. On applies the condition before the intermediate result is created, WHERE applies to the result.

Comment: @Mike Please use the appropriate feature for providing the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate between the total number of students in a batch, and the number of students who *voted* in a given batch, you need to use different fields in your `COUNT` expressions:

```
SELECT
    voters.batch,
    COUNT(*) AS total_batch,
    COUNT(vote.vote_id) AS voted_batch,
    (COUNT(vote.vote_id) * 1.0) / (COUNT(*)) AS percentage
FROM voters
    LEFT JOIN vote ON
        vote.stud_id = voters.stud_id
GROUP BY voters.batch
```

Note that:

1. `COUNT(*)` counts all students, even those who haven't voted (since we're using a `LEFT JOIN`).
2. `COUNT(vote.vote_id)`, i.e. counting by the primary key of the table on the **right** side of the join, only counts students who have voted.
3. We have to multiple one of the `COUNT`s by 1.0, to coerce the result to a decimal (otherwise, you run into integer division).

Finally, you might want to consider changing your table names to be consistent: One is named `voters` (plural), while the other is named `vote` (singular). To avoid starting a religious war, I won't tell you which one to go for.